# Which block type is usually used for a content block on Magento pages?

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, certification

I am preparing for Magento certification exam. There's question on most of study materials that Which block type is usually used for a content block on Magento pages?

Confusion occurs when some sites say answer is `Mage_Core_Block_Text_List` and some say its `Mage_Core_Block_Template`

I think answer should be `Mage_Core_Block_Template` as it uses template file which outputs content from template file whereas `Mage_Core_Block_Text_List` just outputs childs block one by one making it structural block.

Which is the correct answer and why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a significant difference between the two of them. While creating a custom block, it will `extend Mage_Core_Block_Template` almost every time. `Mage_Core_Block_Text_List` is a wrapper in which you can add your own blocks via your `layout.xml`. These `core/text_list` blocks don't have a template. An example of this block is the left or right column of your page (2columns-left.phtml).

So, the block that is used for a content block is `Mage_Core_Block_Template`, since `Mage_Core_Block_Text_List` doesn't have content itself.

Good luck with your exam!